# How to change the width of my Joomla template

Tags: html, css, joomla

I downloaded a template and have been using it on my site, but I don't think its wide enough. I can't find in the html or css where to modify the width of it, where in the template can I change it? Joomla is a bit confusing when it comes to this

http://irishtipster.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have to change `max-width` of the `.container`

Currently it has:

```
.container {
    box-sizing: content-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
    min-width: 220px;
}
```

Comment: I modified it to change it to 1300, here: templates/genius/css/styles.css

Comment: but it has stayed the same

Comment: @PKGrem Have you change it to http://irishtipster.com/ ? like: `max-width: 1300px;` in .container ?